# Automatic deletion of hidden fe_user records in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Is there a way to flag hidden fe_users as deleted after a certain period of time by using standard TYPO3 features? I know that I can use the **Remove deleted records (recycler)** scheduler task to remove records that are flagged as deleted. But is there a scheduler task to flag hidden/disabled records as deleted after a set period of time?

If there is no standard feature, what could be a possible solution to automate the deletion of hidden records after a certain time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no core built-in solution.
Instead you could write your own task.
The most simple solution would be a sql-query, setting deleted=1 where hidden=1 and tstamp < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL -7 DAY)

Comment: @Dman: in the documentation you can find everything you need to create your own scheduler task: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/scheduler/DevelopersGuide/CreatingTasks/Index.html